# R.layout.main error, no solutions have worked

Tags: java, android, package, program-entry-point, setcontentview

I am just beginning to develop for Android. The tutorial book I am using uses the code below, but, put simply, it does not work. As I've searched for an answer, I find that none of the solutions people say have rid them of this error have worked for me. Here is a list of methods that did **not** work.

-Cleaning: It just said it couldn't clean until I resolved the error.

-Building the Project: It built it, but the error did not go away.

-Deleting import R: The error did not go away.

-Renaming import R to import me.package.R: The error persisted.

Here is the code that is generating the error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: IS there no error in your layout files?

Comment: What IDE and build method are you using? I got this error in Intellij IDEA, using Gradle. Deleting .idea and related files and re-importing the project helped.

Comment: do you have the resource? check in folder "res/layout" for main.xml

Comment: I'm guessing that your layout is actually called activity_main since that's what the new ADT wizard thing uses.

Answer (score 0):

your project might need to reference some library jar, due to which your project's R.java is not being generated properly due to some compilation problem.

Comment: it looks more like a comment than an answer, doesn't it?